# how to draw string where substrings have different font styles

Tags: c#, system.drawing.graphics

I am working on a designer like adobe Photoshop written in c#. I have given a task to implement a new feature which is to draw select and apply different font styles to a substring or word within text input and draw that. just like in the below image MS word is doing.

[image]

is there any open source code or a module written in c# doing exact same work?
I have done half of the task but there coming excessive bugs.
my designer looks like.

[image]

is there any open source code available for help?

Comment: Welcome to the grand world of layouting. You'll find it's still a very complex problem, after all the years. Your best bet might be choosing a working layouting system and finding a way to integrate it in what you're trying to do. HTML is used for most layouting nowadays (that's what Word is/was using as well). In any case, the question is off-topic here - just google for layouting engines.

Comment: thanks Luaan atleast i now know that what it is called.. it will help me search it in google. thanks